# Android printing arabic using zebra printer imz320 shows as reversed character

Tags: java, android, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

here is the zpl code from android

```
 String zplcode="^XA^LRN^CI0^XZ\n" +
        "\n" +
        "^XA^CWZ,E:TT0003M_.FNT^FS^XZ\n" +
        "^XA\n" +
        "\n" +
        "^FO10,50^CI28^AZN,50,50^F16^FDZebra Technologies^FS\n" +
        "^FO10,150^CI28^AZN,50,100^F16^FDUNICODE^FS\n" +
        "^FO020,260^CI28^AZN,50,40^F16^FDSwiss 721 Arabic: زيبرة  تكنوليجيز اوربا المحدودة^FS\n" +
        "^PQ1\n" +
        "^XZ";
  mmOutputStream.write(message.getBytes());
```

the result is reversed arabic characters 
any suggestion ?
thanks in advance
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The problem was solved by including this line in the ZPL code:

```
^PA1,1,1,1^FS ^FX Enables Advanced Text ^FS
```

```
 String zplcode="^XA^LRN^CI0^XZ\n" +
    "\n" +
    "^XA^CWZ,E:TT0003M_.FNT^FS^XZ\n" +
    "^XA\n" +
    "\n" +
      "^PA1,1,1,1^FS ^FX Enables Advanced Text ^FS"+
    "^FO10,50^CI28^AZN,50,50^F16^FDZebra Technologies^FS\n" +
    "^FO10,150^CI28^AZN,50,100^F16^FDUNICODE^FS\n" +
    "^FO020,260^CI28^AZN,50,40^F16^FDSwiss 721 Arabic: زيبرة  تكنوليجيز اوربا المحدودة^FS\n" +
    "^PQ1\n" +
    "^XZ";
mmOutputStream.write(message.getBytes());
```

Comment: I still cannot print..any help will be appreicated

Comment: Did you install the Swiss721_UTF-8.zip font on printer?

Comment: The font E:TT0003M_.TTF is present on the printer

Comment: hi, how to print arabic from right to left on the paper?